# SQL Pulling all at once versus individual small queries?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

What is considered better practice?

**A)** Pulling all possible information from database when website PHP page loads, using JOINS on tables that possibly have no relationship (Just grabbing all at once)

**or**

**B)** Pulling data as needed with smaller non-complex queries

Thanks for all input

Comment: Its subjective because it depends on data size, your requirement and your web servers memory sizes and so on.

Comment: there are times and places for both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this entirely depends on the queries.  Often, the bias is toward doing a single query, so the database does the manipulation.  The advantages are:

- One single round trip to the database.
- The database can take advantage of optimizations to return the results from the query.
- All the results are available at one time.

On the other hand, sometimes it is reasonable to run separate queries.  This is true when:

- There are many rows that would have repeated columns (think hundreds or thousands).  The repeated columns can make the result set much larger than it needs to be.
- When different data is needed for different purposes.  If you pulled the data up-front, you would have to pull a larger set to encompass all possible uses of the data.
- When inconsistencies that might arise from running queries at different times are not important.

Comment: regardless of query efficiency there is coding efficiency to worry about to. For the latter coding style and DRY practices can make extra trips worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  My idea was to improve performance mainly.  So far the data I have should not have repeated columns as most of what I would be pulling is profile info from a users table, event info from an event table, etc.. I do have some 'transactional' tables like where this user and this user is going to this event and that is in my signup table, and is an RDBMS so if I designed it well enough then hopefully ONE big pull shouldn't be an issue from what I am understanding.

Comment: @JustinGreenberg . . . Assuming you are using the data (and not pulling it back for subsequent processing), then that is fine.